# How to concatenate node adress and string xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Hey i have a problem

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
     <xs:attribute name="a"/>
     <xs:attribute name="b"/>
 </xs:complesType>
```

Ok so we have type A which has atrribute a and b

I have in variable x - adress of node of type A and variable y - attributes of Type A ( a and b)
I want to check which attributes that particular node ( variable x) has and if i do

```
 <xsl:if test="$x/@a">
 </xsl:if>
```

and

```
 <xsl:if test="$x/@b">
 </xsl:if>
```

it works  but i need to do it automaticly which is

```
<xsl:for-each select =$x>  
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select = $y>
        <xsl:if test=" concatenate $path @ and .>

       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please show an example of the input, how the variables are defined and the expected output - see [mcve]. Knowing which version your processor supports would also be useful.